# A question on weakly convergent sequences in Hilbert spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, proof-verification, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $\left(a_n\right)$ is a bounded sequence in $H.$ Then there exists a subsequence $\left(a_{n_k}\right)$ of $\left(a_n\right)$ which converges weakly in $H.$ On the other hand, $\left\Vert a_{n_k}\right\Vert$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R},$ thereby it follows from the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem that there exists a subsequence $\left(a_{n_{k_m}}\right)$ of $\left(a_{n_k}\right)$ such that $\left\Vert a_{n_{k_m}}\right\Vert$ is convergent in $\mathbb{R}.$ Besides, $\left(a_{n_{k_m}}\right)$ is also a weakly convergent sequence. Therefore, $\left(a_{n_{k_m}}\right)$ is a convergent sequence in $H.$

I can't find any mistake in this proof. Please show me a mistake? Thank you!

Comment: Convergence of $(\|a_n\|)$ does not imply the convergence of $(a_n)$. Consider a sequence $(a_n)$ formed by enumerating a countable orthonormal subset of an infinite Hilbert space. Then $\|a_n\|=1$ for all $n$ and $(a_n)$ converges weakly to 0, but $(a_n)$ does not converge.

Comment: $\left(u_n\right)$ admits a subsequence $\left(u_{n_k}\right)$ which converges weakly to $u_0$ in $H.$

$\left(u_{n_k}\right)$ converges to $u_0$ in the norm of $H,$ i.e. $\Vert u_{n_k} \Vert_{H} \rightarrow \Vert u_{0} \Vert _{H}.$

Then $u_{n_k}$ converges to $u_0$ in $H.$

Comment: $$\begin{aligned}
\Vert u_{n_k} - u_0 \Vert_{H_0^1}^2 &= \langle  u_{n_k} - u_0 , u_{n_k} - u_0 \rangle \\
&= \Vert u_{n_k}  \Vert_{H_0^1}^2 +\Vert  u_0 \Vert_{H_0^1}^2 -2\langle  u_{n_k}, u_0 \rangle \\
&\rightarrow 0
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: How do you know that $\|u_{n_k}\|$ converges to $\|u_0\|$?

Comment: That means $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N_{\epsilon} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\left\vert \left\Vert u_{n_k}\right\Vert - \left\Vert u_{0}\right\Vert \right\vert < \epsilon$ for all $k>N_{\epsilon}$

Comment: please show me!

Comment: What I mean is that, it is not true in general. You always have $\|u_0\| \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \| u_n \|$ for weakly convergent sequence $u_n \rightharpoonup u_0$, but the strict inequality is possible when $\dim H = \infty$. (Thus the norm $\|\cdot\|$ is only weakly lower semicontinuous.) The example I showed you is such an instance.